# Macros argument evaluation in C++

Tags: c++, macros, inline

I don't understand what is the reason that macros don't evaluate their argument only once (like inline functions), but each time it is used in the code.

For example:

(the example is taken from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=msvc-170)

In this code there is a macro:

```
// inline_functions_macro.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define toupper(a) ((a) >= 'a' && ((a) <= 'z') ? ((a)-('a'-'A')):(a))

int main() {
   char ch;
   printf_s("Enter a character: ");
   ch = toupper( getc(stdin) );
   printf_s( "%c", ch );
}
//  Sample Input:  xyz
// Sample Output:  Z
```

Compared to this code, with the equivalent inline function:

```
// inline_functions_inline.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

inline char toupper( char a ) {
   return ((a >= 'a' && a <= 'z') ? a-('a'-'A') : a );
}

int main() {
   printf_s("Enter a character: ");
   char ch = toupper( getc(stdin) );
   printf_s( "%c", ch );
}
```

Comment: Macros are a text substitutions. They are not functions.

Comment: Macros are not functions.  They are preprocessor text replacement, that's all.  Nothing more, nothing less.  It's like your source code literally has the substituted text done by the preprocessor, hence the compiler complains at the usage of every macro, not the macro itself.

Comment: An important understanding is that the macros are expanded before compilation, in what is commonly referred to as the "preprocessing phase".

Comment: Try expanding the macro with the following arguments, "hello" and 3.1415269.  This should show you why functions are preferred to macros.

Answer (score 3):

Macros are not very smart.  They simply perform **text substitution** before compilation begins.

The code:

```
#define toupper(a) ((a) >= 'a' && ((a) <= 'z') ? ((a)-('a'-'A')):(a))

int main() {
   char ch = toupper( getc(stdin) );
}
```

Instructs the preprocessor to change this code and instead hand this to the compiler:

```
int main() {
   char ch = ((getc(stdin)) >= 'a' && ((getc(stdin)) <= 'z') ? ((getc(stdin))-('a'-'A')):(getc(stdin)));
}
```

You can observe that `toupper` was replaced by the defined expression, while every occurance of `a` is replaced by whatever **text** was passed as the macro parameter.  It's not a value or an expression - it's just text.

Aside from the problems you observe, you may also discover that compiler errors will show this substituted code.  Code that you don't see in your source file.